# Delete text starting on a specific character until the end

Tags: regex, google-sheets, replace, re2, find-replace

I'm using Google Sheets and I have this dataset with over 100 000 lines, and in one specific column (F) I want to delete all text starting from the dollar sign until the end. How do I do it?

[image: dataset with the collumn I want to edit]

For instance,

```
:
2.182.398
:
$28.34M
```

should become

```
:
2.182.398
:
```

Comment: I have no experience with regular expressions, all substitutions I've made so far were with the Replace tool (Ctrl + H), where I would replace, for instance, a minus with a blank space, and all minuses would disappear. This problem is more complex because the number after the dollar sign is always different, so I need something that will say "In every line of this collumn, everything that appears after the dollar sign must disappear"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd>

type in:

```
(\$\d.+)
```

and hit **Replace all**:

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much!! What would the code be, if instead of erasing everything from dollarsign onward, it erased everything UNTIL the dollarsign appears, leaving only the $28.34M ? (basically the reverse of what you did)

Comment: you would need to run it twice. first time with `\n` and 2nd time with `(.+)\$`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if google sheet works like excel. but you can try text to columns if possible. Use '$' as delimiter. Another way is to use the replace function with regex in Google app script.